# How get `date` with a certain format from JSP input form?

Tags: mysql, jsp, spring-mvc

In this project, I would like to get a date from data that user just input using form using JSP. After that, I would like to store the input to MySQL.

This is my JSP file:

```
<form:form id="regForm" modelAttribute="assignment" action="successAddAssignment" method="post">
    <table align="center">
        <tr>
            <td>
            <form:label path="date">Date</form:label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form:input path="date" name="date" type="date" id="date" pattern="yyyy/MM/dd"/> <span class="inst">(YYYY-MM-DD)</span>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <form:button id="addAssignment" name="addAssignment">Submit</form:button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr></tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

This is my Dao file :

```
 public void addAssignment(Assignment assignment){
    String sql = "insert into assignment values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    jdbcTemplate.update(sql, assignment.getId(), assignment.getDate(), assignment.getTime(), assignment.getCode_module(), assignment.getName_module(), assignment.getDescription());

}
```

But, when I run my program, the result is like this:
    [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpbS6.png)

I got an error when I want to submit the data "date". My question is How do I create the date format from "yyyy/MM/dd" to "dd/MM/yyyy"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no *pattern* tag in JSP. You probably need to convert a string into a Date object with JS or in the controller.

Something like this may work in the controller:

```
String dateReceived = "2018-04-24";
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date dateFormatted = dateFormat.parse(dateReceived);
```

You may want to check [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: do I need change type="date" to type="text" in <form:input path="date" name="date" type="date" id="date">? because you said that I need to convert a string into a Date @Natalia Gutiérrez

Comment: Maybe someone could give some more info about this, but as far as I know, typical jsp *form:input* does not have any *type* tag...